# Tableau data source with Athena custom query

Tags: datasource, amazon-athena, tableau-api

I'm getting the below error on Tableau Desktop when using the custom query, I'm successfully able to connect and see contents from the table when directly drag the table to query builder section on Tableau Desktop.

Datasource used: AWS Athena

Driver version: AthenaJDBC42_2.0.2

Tableau Desktop version: 10.4

```
com.tableausoftware.jdbc.TableauJDBCException: Error reading metadata for executed query: SELECT * FROM ( select * from tablename ) "TableauSQL" LIMIT 0 [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Only one sql statement is allowed. Got: SELECT * FROM ( select * from tablename ;) "TableauSQL" LIMIT 0
There was a Java error.
Unable to connect to the server "Athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the ; from the subquery - That always throws errors for me

Comment: You query confuses me, doing a select * from a select * is the same thing, right? You also have limit 0? Remove the limit 0 to have no limit on the results

Comment: My query is only  `select * from tablename` I'm not sure how the outer select has come and that is creating the problem, I think.

Comment: What happens when you call out column names?

Comment: Its the same prblem

Comment: I think custom query with Athena is not working with Tableau

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. 
To provide some clarity to the above - the outer query is being added by Tableau. Here is my simple query and the error being returned by Tableau. [image: Tableau Athena Custom SQL error]

I was able to resolve by changing my query to refer to my table in the form "database"."table" and remove the closing ;

This custom query then worked for me:

[image: successful query]